# Alias for rebasing master into feature on daily basis

Tags: git

We've master branch and develop branch. And developers usually create their own branch for any new features and then create pull request for this new branch to merge it in develop.

Since other developers keep adding new features and merge it in develop, I need an alias which I can run daily in the morning to keep my feature branch up-to date with develop branch. Can someone provide me with the alias which will use rebase option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the alias.

```
$ git config alias.update "pull origin develop --rebase"
```

Now when you want to update your local `feature` branch with `origin/develop` branch changes. Simply run:

```
$ git checkout feature 
$ git update
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **branch.autosetuprebase** in the configuration to

```
git config  branch.autosetuprebase always
```

or at the global level

```
git config --global branch.autosetuprebase always
```

This will force all new branches to automatically use rebase when issuing the pull command.
You can always merge using the get merge command.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull